# How to find index of an array which has maximum value in dataframe using python?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, max

I have a dataframe which has array of elements, i would like to get the index value of the maximum number in the array using python,

Desired output:

```
Elements    Max Value Index

[3,4,5]              2

[2,0,1]              0
```

I tried using:

```
df['Max Value Index'] = df["Elements"].apply(lambda x:max(x))
```

It gives me the maximum value,
, I just need the index number, i tried many ways but not able to get that, can anybody please help?

Answer (score 1):

Try idxmax(x)

```
df['Max Value Index'] = df["Elements"].apply(lambda x:idxmax(x))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`numpy.argmax`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html):

```py
df['Max Value Index'] = df['Elements'].apply(lambda l:np.argmax(l))
```

Or in straight python:

```
df['Max Value Index'] = df["Elements"].apply(lambda l:l.index(max(l)))
```

Output:

```
    Elements  Max Value Index
0  [3, 4, 5]                2
1  [2, 0, 1]                0
```